# Until I reset CMOS and RAM, monitor, mouse and keyboard don't get signal

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

Since past few days I'm facing this problem. This started when I began using SoundBlaster X G1.

My operating system is Fedora 29 KDE.

Most of the time I suspend my computer, since I connected this SoundBlaster X G1, my computer is not waking up from suspend. I wake the computer by pressing a keyboard button, CPU starts, mouse turns on but monitor and keyboard don't get signal.

When I reset and turn off and turn on the CPU, only mouse and CPU turn on, keyboard and monitor don't get signal.

Either resetting the CMOS or RAM seems to resolve the problem, every time I'm facing this problem, I'm resetting both of these. After resetting these, when I turn on the CPU, it starts for few seconds and turns off and restarts again, like this it happens few times and then finally it starts with monitor signal, keyboard signal and mouse.

Could this be caused by virus in SoundBlaster X G1?

In addition to the above, I'm also facing this problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533541/audiono-input-or-output-devices-found

Comment: @harrymc I'm not the first person to use turning on and off CPU to refer to turning the computer on and off by pressing power button. I'm not the first person to say resetting the CMOS and RAM to taking out the CMOS battery and reinserting it, resetting the RAM also means taking out RAM modules and reinserting it.

Comment: You are in any case the first I encounter here, as these terms are ambiguous. Someone deleted my comment in which I asked whether the power supply is sufficient since the installation of the SoundBlaster.

Comment: @harrymc The sound card is a USB sound card and I have thermaltake's 500W PSU. So I think it should be more than enough.